# Reactable R - Change the Maximum Number of Rows per Page from 10 to 5

Tags: r, reactable

I want to limit the number of rows per page in reactable from 10 to 5.

Here is a reproducible sample

```
set.seed(250)
df <- tibble(x = sample(x = 1:20))
reactable(df)
```

Right now, when you run this code, there are two pages of 10 rows each. I want four pages of 5 rows each.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the default Page size (10) with the `defaultPageSize` argument (https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/examples.html#pagination)

```
library(reactable)
set.seed(250)
df <- dplyr::tibble(x = sample(x = 1:20))
reactable(df, defaultPageSize = 5)
```