# Add a subheader to a "reactable" table in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactable

I'd like to create a "reactable" table in R Shiny.

But I need it to have a breakdown of three subheaders under all the headers.

[image: subheadings from excel]

The three subheaders point towards figures that are derived from a separate table. Q1 is "Period 1" which can be toggled around a bit from a slider input. As is Q2. "All" is "for all of time". The subheader titles themselves won't change.

It would also be useful to have more than 10 rows displayed at once time in the reactable. So if anyone knows how to extend this as well, I'd be grateful.

Here is a typical reactable Shiny table with a single header and only 10 rows of data. I need to see ~30 at a time.

[image: reactable example]

Comment: for max rows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71740599/reactable-r-change-the-maximum-number-of-rows-per-page-from-10-to-5 and for subheaders: https://glin.github.io/reactable/reference/colGroup.html

Comment: @Julian Many thanks, I knew there must be simple solutions. I just couldn't find them.

Comment: your welcome, let me know if you run into troubles!